# Symfony file environment variable processor not working in console command

Tags: php, symfony6

I have a registered service where I inject the content of a json as argument (see followed configuration, `App\Service\Authenticator` service)

```
parameters:
    env(LDAP_CONFIG_FILE): '../auth.json'
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
    
    App\Service\Authenticator:
        arguments:
            $config: '%env(json:file:resolve:LDAP_CONFIG_FILE)%'
            $environment: '%env(APP_ENV)%'
```

When I try to inject this service in a controller, this works fine as expected. But when I inject the service into a command I get this error :

```
> php bin/console app:execute

  [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:

In EnvVarProcessor.php line 136:

  File "../auth.json" not found (resolved from "resolve:LDAP_CONFIG_FILE").

  Command "app:execute" is not defined.
```

And if I replace `env(LDAP_CONFIG_FILE)` by `auth.json` it work in a command but not in a controller anymore.

How can I configure to make it work in both commands and controllers ?

Edit: I found a temporary fix with the `default` processor but I really want a clean solution.

Comment: Have you tried something like `"%kernel.project_dir%/auth.json"` as shown in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html)?

Comment: It is working. I request a change in documentation to the example of `env(file:FOO)` will include this and avoid other people to get the same issue as mine